# What size object could wreak havoc on a world but not "destroy" it?

Tags: space

So what size comet/meteor/rogue planet could wreak havoc on a populated world without killing off intelligent life entirely or actually ruining the planet for life? Assume the world being affected is roughly the size of Earth, and the object is passing at a distance somewhere between the Earth and Moon. By "wreak havoc", I mean that the object would cause temporary climate change, floods, fires, devastation from impacts by smaller trailing objects, etc. Assume a roughly medieval/renaissance era human population lives on this planet - how big of an object would it take to cause enough problems to wipe out population centers and maybe 90% of the people and essentially revert them to a stone age society?

Comment: How widespread is the human population? While Europe was experiencing the Reconnaissance other civilizations were at different stages of development. Also, it will be very difficult to come up with something which equally affects all these different populations. Is it acceptable that everyone else get wiped out but only this one particular group survives (while losing their knowledge and technology)? Tell us more about the human population on your world. Also, whether they revert to the stone age or not will greatly depend on their culture, I believe.

Comment: @AndreiROM I think the Reconnaissance sounds a little bit more like a post-apocalyptic period. Like, after the fiery meteor apocalypse. :)

Answer (score 4):

The one that hit 65 million years (killed off the dinosaurs) ago was 6 miles/10 KM wide, which would probably be far too large. The one that hit Siberia in 1908 (Tunguska) was 60-190 METERS in size, yet devastated the area for miles. So pick a size in that range. True GLOBAL climate changing impacts will be on the larger size, though depending on the impact site you can cause a lot of havoc to a society. Imagine a hit into the Mediterranean that caused tidal waves to hit all the coastal civilizations of the area. Disrupting trade and swamping coastal cities could cripple the empires and cause substantial population loss even if it doesn't destroy a lot directly. Even bronze age cultures had significant trade and food transport mechanisms to sustain their cities, disrupt those and famine results pretty quickly.

Sounds like you want something big to PASS BY Earth without hitting it directly (kinda like that old Thundarr cartoon). In that case, a shower of 60-150 meter objects in the wake of the comet could strike the earth. In just a 24 hour period they would hit across the globe (though depending on the speed of the comet and the length of the tail the transit time could be much longer). Many smaller impacts would leave cities and fields ruined, but not so damaged that there is a "nuclear winter" scenario that would probably kill off all large mammals including humans or blast the planet down to bedrock, crack tectonic plates, or the like.

I don't think you would have many significant gravity effects unless something like a neutron star passed by, but that could have a gravity well twice that of our Sun, which would probably knock planets out of their orbits and really screw things up.

Comment: Anything of a mass larger than the moon will cause tidal effects

Comment: Sure, but if it passed by in a few days I'm not sure it would cause lasting damage (like plucking people off the surface, triggering fault lines, or driving rivers to jump their beds). Might cause a big tidal surge though...

Comment: It would change both the Moon and Earth's orbits. This would rearrange oceans permanently. The effect on ecosystems would be disastrous due to how fast the change would occur.

Comment: Would it? A moon sized object passing by quickly might alter orbits but I don't think it would cause an immediate disastrous effect though that may depend on where both objects are in relation to Earth. If it is moving at the speed of Haleys Comet (250,000 km/hr) then it would cover the distance between Earth and the moon in an hour and a half (384,000 km). So the time it has to exert a gravitational effect could be very short as the object shoots through the system. No doubt orbits would be changed, but I don't think they would have a drastic immediate affect.

Comment: Humans are much more adaptable than dinosaurs, and even these medieval humans tech will help. (and the stores) so I recon a few of them would survive a 10Km dinosaur killer (the mice did)

Comment: I dunno, much larger energy requirements for humans. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event at least suggests nothing larger than 55 pounds survived other than some turtles and crocodiles. Certainly an isolated, sheltered tribe of humans MIGHT survive but it would be far less than the 10% wanted by the OP. Survivability is tricky. Primitive peoples can live off the land better but they lack the ability to forecast and lay in stores. Modern humans could conceivably build a greenhouse shelter to ride out a 10 km hit, don't think primitives could.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to that. One is based on physics, one in psychology.

- **Physics**

If the object will not collide with neither Earth nor Moon, it has to be massive enough for its gravity to influence Earth and the Moon somehow. I don't have a simulator on me right now to test it (I have a couple of these in mu home computer), but out of my mind a Pluto-sized object would do. If it were as massive as our Moon, then civilization wrecking damage would surely ensue from its flyby.

That's because such an object passing by the Earth would change Earth's orbit around the Sun, and the Moon's orbit around Earth, in a permanent way. This would in the very least cause extremely rapid changes to the tides of Earth's oceans - tsunamis would happen all around the world during the flyby, and after that, no shore would ever have the same tides it used to have before.

If the object is massive enough (and I might edit this question later to mention some specific amount of mass - but right now I think something as massive as Venus/Earth) it may even cause global Earthquakes because it will pull the side of Earth that is closest to it with more force than it will pull the other side. This will have an immediate geographical effect, and lots of death and destruction.

Remember that his kind of effect is caused by mass, not by size. A neutron star or a black hole the size of an apartment building passing midway between Earth and the Moon might cause a more dramatic effect than the one I am describing here, due to their extreme density!

- **Psychology**

Of course, since your civilization is medieval, you can count on people going crazy just by seeing a comet passing by. Let people be their own nemesis.

In our own real world, many civilizations had riots when comets passed by. I'll let you do some research on that. Since we are talking about fictional worlds here, we can imagine a world where all the major civilizations have one or more prophecies related to the passing of a comet. When the comet comes, civil wars ensue, perhaps even on a global level. The populations can't handle the aftermath and go back to the stone age.

Ok, people won't cause floods, hurricanes etc. But they can cause fires, blight, and spread diseases through biological warfare (it existed during the middle ages - catapult the bodies of those who died from disease into an enemy castle, for example). Might be just as devastating.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends in where it hits, level of technology of the civilization.

An object the size of a couple Buses hitting NYC, London, Paris, etc is much different then the same object landing in the ocean. A city hit would devastate the world economy for years to come and could lead to a total break down of society.

It would say an object about the size of a small stadium the NY metro area. 10 of millions dead instantly. Basically the entire NY metro area is ruble. One if the busiest ports and airports in the world gone. The finical center of the world gone. Have it hit during a UN general Assembly, then a large majority of world leaders gone.

Soon economic collapse will set in. Then society will collapse.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cutoff in asteroid size, which I think is a little over a kilometer in diameter (the exact value depends on the composition, the speed and angle of impact, and whether it comes down in the ocean or on land).  Below this size, an impact causes only "local" destruction, even though "local" is a relative term: a 1-km asteroid could easily wipe out an entire country.

However, if an asteroid is much bigger than 1 km (like the impact that killed the dinosaurs), then it will eject a sizable amount of the Earth's crust, mixed with its own material, into space.  Some of this material will not quite reach space, and will come back down, all over Earth.  The heat from the fragments burning up in the atmosphere will start a global firestorm that will set all forests, cities and crops on fire.  Afterwards, the upper atmosphere will be filled with ash that will take months or even years to settle, darkening the sky and further killing plants and reducing global temperatures.

The initial firestorm would be comparable in intensity to, for example, the Dresden bombing in WWII, but everywhere on Earth, not just one city.  Some humans would survive by taking shelter in sufficiently sturdy cellars.  However, the survivors that emerge would find all buildings, crops and forests, together with almost all livestock and wild animals, destroyed.  The sky would be pitch-black, and temperatures would be rapidly dropping.  It is unclear whether a human population could reestablish itself under these conditions, but if it did, it would certainly be greatly reduced in size and thrown back to a Stone Age society.

It is not so clear what the maximum size for a survivable asteroid impact is.  The bigger the asteroid, the more material will be ejected and fall back down, and the more intense the firestorm.  At some point, even cellars would heat up past the point of survivability, and only people in deep mines could survive.  But when they emerge, they would find no life left on the surface, and would have no means to feed themselves.

As a very simple estimate, let's say that the dinosaur-killing impact (10 km) is "survivable", in the sense that some animal species survived it, while a 100 km impact quite clearly isn't (at that point, the ground shock wave becomes a problem).  Taking a logarithmic average, a 30-km impact might be at the limit of survivability.

EDIT:

I am slightly confused by the wording of your question.  It seems like you might want the object to pass by, rather than directly impact the planet?  In that case, the main danger is changing the planet's orbit or the orbits of its satellites.  This can happen to a significant degree if the passing object is roughly the same mass as the planet, or at least not much smaller (for example, Mars passing between the Earth and the Moon wouldn't change either one's orbit by much, as it is much lighter than the Earth, and its gravitational field would be only a small perturbation compared to the Earth's).  As for impacts from "trailing objects", these are basically the main object's satellites, and of course there is a chance of one of them impacting the planet.  In this case, it's the size of the trailing object that matters, for which see the above discussion.

Comment: Do you have a source on a size threshold?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt:  can't find an original source that is open and free, unfortunately.  This one is good, but it requires registration or money: https://www.nap.edu/catalog/12842/defending-planet-earth-near-earth-object-surveys-and-hazard-mitigation  Some key results are summarized here:  https://www.fallingstar.com/danger.php .  Note how in the "impact effect" plots the number of fatalities goes up sharply (by a factor of 100 or more) for asteroids > 1 km, due to "global effects".